# python combining a range and a list of numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
range(5, 15) [1, 1, 5, 6, 10, 10, 10, 11, 17, 28]
range(6, 24) [4, 10, 10, 10, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 30]
range(7, 41) [9, 18, 19, 23, 23, 26, 28, 40, 42, 44]
range(11, 49) [9, 23, 24, 27, 29, 31, 43, 44, 45, 45]
range(38, 50) [1, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50]
```

I get the above outpout from a print command from a function. What I really want is a combined list of the range, for example in the top line 5,6,7...15,1,1,5,6 etc.
The output range comes from

```
range_draws=range(int(lower),int(upper))
```

which I naively thought would give a range. The other numbers come from a sliced list.

Could someone help me to get the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `range()` function returns a special [range object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) to save on memory (no need to keep all the numbers in memory when only the start, end and step size will do). Cast it to a list to 'expand' it:

```
list(yourrange) + otherlist
```

To quote the documentation:

> The advantage of the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) type over a regular [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) or [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) is that a [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the `start`, `stop` and `step` values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).