# How to delete many columns in python with one line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to delete the following columns on my dataframe: 1,2,101:117,121:124,126.

So far the two ways I have found to delete columns is:

```
df.drop(df.columns[2:6],axis=1)
df.drop(df.columns[[0,3,5]],axis=1)
```

however if I try

```
df.drop(df.columns[1,2,101:117,121:124],axis=1)
```

I get a "too many indices" error

I also tried this

```
a=df.drop(df.columns[[1,2]],axis=1)
b=a.drop(a.columns[99:115],axis=1)
c=b.drop(b.columns[102:105],axis=1)
d=c.drop(c.columns[103],axis=1)
```

but this isn't deleting the columns I'm wanting to for some reason.

Comment: This might be of some help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538536/deleting-multiple-columns-based-on-column-names-in-pandas

Comment: Maybe try deleting the columns in the opposite order?  If you delete cols 1 and 2,  col 99 becomes col 97.

Comment: How single indices and ranges can be combined into a single list is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14519521/5350621. In your case index = [1,2] + list(range(101, 117)) + ... and then df.drop(df.columns[index],axis=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to slice:

```
import numpy as np

df.drop(columns=df.columns[np.r_[1, 2, 101:117, 121:124, 126]])
```

---

```
import pandas pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (2, 130)))
df.drop(columns=df.columns[np.r_[1, 2, 101:117, 121:124, 126]])
#     0    3    4    5    6 ... 120 124 125  127
#0    6    1    3    7    2 ...   8   7   2    6
#1    1    9    2    5    3 ...   7   3   9    4
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> df.drop(df.columns[[indexes_of_columns_you_want_to_delete]], axis=1,
>   inplace=True)

Comment: Is this how you would format it: 

```
dfcomm.drop(dfcomm.columns[[1,2,101:117,121:124,126]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Becuase I'm getting an invalid syntax error

Comment: This will not work with the OP's indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
input_df.drop(input_df.columns[[np.r_[0,2:4]]],axis=1, inplace = True)
```